# When i speak it provides output (result) only 1 time and do nothing for next inputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, speech-recognition

Here is my code,i want to continuously get results according to my given inputs but application provide output only once and then do nothing. I think there must loop on result class,, actually not sure where. please help me :)
SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        InitializeSpeechRecognizer();

    }
    private async void InitializeSpeechRecognizer()
    {
        speechRecognizer.RecognitionQualityDegrading += speechRecognizer_RecognitionQualityDegrading;
        await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
        // Start recognition.

        SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult= await speechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync();
            textBox1.Text = speechRecognitionResult.Text;
        // Compile the constraint.


    }

    private async void speechRecognizer_RecognitionQualityDegrading(
Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer sender,
Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionQualityDegradingEventArgs args)
    {
        // Create an instance of a speech synthesis engine (voice).
        var speechSynthesizer =
            new Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

        // If input speech is too quiet, prompt the user to speak louder.
        if (args.Problem == Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionAudioProblem.TooQuiet)
        {
            // Generate the audio stream from plain text.
            Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesisStream stream;
            try
            {
                stream = await speechSynthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Try speaking louder");
                stream.Seek(0);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                stream = null;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should register to **SpeechRecognized** event and set the resulting text to the textbox in the event handler. It is only working once because InitializeSpeechRecognizer is called once and that is not the right place to do this.

**Edit:** Simplest implementation would be something like this;

```
SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer();
sr.SpeechRecognized += (s, e) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Recognized Text :{0}, Confidence {1}",
                               e.Result.Text,e.Result.Confidence); 
        };
```

There is also a winforms example in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: still not working, actually i want to get voice input not want to compare already mentioned grammar string/char.

Comment: The sample in the link i gave parses audio to text, isn't that what you are after?

Comment: actually i want to use  SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult; result , it is providing but only 1 time.

Comment: e.Result in the sample code above is of type SpeechRecognitionResult. SpeechRecognized event is triggered everytime any words are recognized and the result is passed as a parameter to your handler.

Comment: ahan, SpeechRecognized is giving an error. I think it is due to API difference  i am working on UWP and you give code for winform.